# Autoloader from Composer clashing with other one

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I am work on legacy app that includes dozens and dozens of different php scripts, all written before Composer was widespread in use.

I needed to use a package (for sending email) only available through Composer, so I created a composer directory and included it into one script like so:

```
include_once("/home/soccer/src/autoload.php"); // the old autoloader
require '/home/soccer/src/Mailgun/vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;
```

Now the problem is that Composer's autoload (shown in line 2) works fine, and I can send mail, however now the important libraries from line 1 do not work:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DB' not found in .....
```

There is a file at:

```
/home/soccer/src/DB.php
```

that is the most basic MySQL db loader imaginable. I tried adding a namespace to it with:

```
namespace Footyscores;
```

and then in the PHP script adding **Footyscores** to the function call, but no luck there, same error.

Here is the legacy autoloader:

```
include_once "/home/soccer/src/settings.php";

function __autoload($class)
{
  global $srcDir;

  $parts = explode('\\', $class);
  $file = end($parts);
  include_once $srcDir . $file . '.php';
}
```

How is I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Post the actual code of your legacy autoloader. While you *can* have more than one autoloader, they must be defined in a particular way.

Comment: ok @sammitch posting now

Comment: iokay I fixed it using spl_autoload